# WooCommerce: issue setting attributes with wp_set_object_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webshop

I need to set product's attributes via PHP code.
According to other threads on StackOverflow, there's the method **wp_set_object_terms**. Unfortunately it is not working as it is supposed to do in my case:

For example, there is an attribute named "Hersteller", slug "hersteller".
And there is a product, ID 593, with no "hersteller" attribute set.

**I tried the following code to fill the attribute:**

```
wp_set_object_terms(593, 'Alpina', 'pa_hersteller' , false);
```

When I'm attempting to display the attribute on the product page, there is no output, so it seems that the wp_set_object_terms process hasn't been successful.
Following code produces an empty output:

```
$product->get_attribute('hersteller');
```

Furthermore, the attribute "hersteller" isn't even listed in the attribute list in the admin backend menue.

To debug the problem I've also tried the following code:

```
$attributes = get_post_meta( 593,  '_product_attributes' ); 
print_r($attributes);
```

resulting in the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pa_marken] => Array ( [name] => pa_marken [value] => [position] => 0 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_kategorien] => Array ( [name] => pa_kategorien [value] => [position] => 1 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_referenznummer] => Array ( [name] => pa_referenznummer [value] => [position] => 2 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_herstellergarantie] => Array ( [name] => pa_herstellergarantie [value] => [position] => 3 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_schlagwoerter] => Array ( [name] => pa_schlagwoerter [value] => [position] => 4 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_lieferzeit] => Array ( [name] => pa_lieferzeit [value] => [position] => 5 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) ) )
```

Am I using the wp_set_object_terms method essentially wrong?
I don't know what to do anymore now. May anyone here can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your code like this:

```
wp_set_object_terms(593, 'Alpina', 'pa_hersteller' , true);
```

And try again.

According to the function in WordPress Codex

```
<?php wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ); ?>
```

> **$append** (bool) (optional) If true, tags will be appended to the
>   object. If false, tags will replace existing tags (Default: False)

So if you change the $append to true it may be works =)

Comment: So far, I've tried that aswell!
That also doesn't work, because the append-boolean is just to enable multiple values set to an attribute.

If append is false, the existing attribute value/s are being overwritten, if append is true, the existing attributes are still there and the new one gets added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the attributes output you provided, it seems that you are targeting the wrong taxonomy, I can see `pa_herstellergarantie`in the following output :

```
Array ( ..... 
    [pa_herstellergarantie] => Array ( 
                 [name] => pa_herstellergarantie 
                 [value] => 
                 [position] => 3 
                 [is_visible] => 1 
                 [is_variation] => 0 
                 [is_taxonomy] => 1 )......
```

Change your code to:

```
wp_set_object_terms(593, 'Alpina', 'pa_herstellergarantie' , false);
```

Also a note to say that `wp_set_object_terms` will not create the taxonomy.
If the taxonomy doesn't exist it will throw an `Invalid taxonomy` error message.

If `pa_herstellergarantie` and `pa_hersteller` are 2 distinct taxonomies, then ensure that `pa_hersteller` exists before using `wp_set_object_terms`

Comment: Both attributes, `pa_hersteller` and `pa_herstellergarantie` are distinct taxonomies. Both are also existing - database screenshot, table `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`: [link](http://i.imgur.com/YOVqdSk.png).  
  
The only difference between `pa_herstellergarantie` (which stores the warranty given by the product's producer) and `pa_hersteller` (which stores the producer) is, that pa_herstellergarantie is already set per admin backend menue and pa_hersteller is not set for this specific product!

Comment: Interestingly, when I try the code `wp_set_object_terms( 593, 'Alpina', 'pa_herstellergarantie' , false);` it works! Attribute "herstellergarantie" gets successfully set to "Alpina" - but instead of **herstellergarantie** the attribute **hersteller** should be "Alpina"! The only difference is, **pa_herstellergarantie** has been set before in the admin menue for this specific product, **pa_hersteller** hasn't been set for this product (but it's existing in the database, screenshot above!).

Comment: Try clearing the transients and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Now I've tried the following code: `wc_delete_product_transients( 593 ); wp_set_object_terms( 593, 'TestForStackoverflow', 'pa_hersteller' , false);` The output of **get_post_meta** is still the same, **pa_hersteller** still isn't listed in the attribute array of product 593.

Comment: The code I've given in my above comment should set **pa_hersteller** of product 593 to `TestForStackoverflow`. Interestingly, when I try to debug and display all values for **pa_hersteller** the term 'TestForStackoverflow' is listed somehow. `$terms = get_terms("pa_hersteller");
 foreach ($terms as $term)
  echo $term->name."|".$term->term_id;` **But still, the product 593 has no attribute _pa_hersteller_ set!** Output of _get_terms_ is: **TestForStackoverflow|116**

Comment: If `pa_hersteller` is in the database, it means it got created at some point. How it got created will probably lead us to the solution. How did you create that taxonomy?

Comment: I created the `pa_hersteller` attribute, just as any other attribute, in the WooCommerce admin menue (/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes). More of interest is, that somehow 3 new attributes got added (shown in the admin menue). Screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/8zui5uR.png) ----- **I'm not sure if I stated the problem clearly. I don't want to create a new attribute (as obviously 3 new attributes were created)! I want to assign an attribute value of an existing (= already created manually before) attribute to a product!**

Answer (score 0):

To set attributes programatically you must update the post meta with the taxonomy's data after setting the terms, like this

```
wp_set_object_terms(593, 'Alpina', 'pa_hersteller' , false);
$thedata = array('pa_hersteller' => array(
    name' => 'pa_hersteller',
    'value' => '',
    'is_visible' => '0',
    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));

update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_product_attributes', $thedata);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Do you know if this works recursively. Like I've set a lot of attributes pragmatically. Can I use the 2 line and below to essentially say, "hey, by the way I update this a while back" ?